# SpringBoot JdbcTemplate with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-data, jdbctemplate

I have a SpringBoot app. that uses JdbcTemplate to connect to a SQL Server DB, using this syntax:

```
int numOfRowsAffected = remoteJdbcTemplate.update(
                "insert into dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_]  " +
                "(Entry No_, Posting Date, Resource No_, Job No_, Work Type, Quantity, Unit of Measure, Description, Company Name, Created Date-Time ) " +
                        " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",

                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getEntryNo(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getPostingDate(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getResourceNo(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getJobNo(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getWorkType(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getQuantity(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getUnitOfMeasure(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getDescription(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getCompanyName(),
                        atresMediaTimeRegistr.getCreatedDate());
```

But I got this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'No_'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column names are with spaces, use square brackets `[]` for the column names like following.

```
int numOfRowsAffected = remoteJdbcTemplate.update(
                "insert into dbo.[ATRESMEDIA Resource Time Registr_]  " +
                "([Entry No_], [Posting Date], [Resource No_], [Job No_], [Work Type], [Quantity], [Unit of Measure], [Description], [Company Name], [Created Date-Time] ) " +
                        " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
```

For example if you try query like following in SQL

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(Entry No_)
SELECT 1
```

You will get the same error.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'No_'.